# Difference between sudo -s and sudo su in mac os

Tags: linux, sudo

Both sudo -s and sudo su makes user root. is there any some difference?

With sudo -s 
[image]

with sudo su

[image]

Comment: [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com) is maybe a more suiteable place for these kind of questions...

Comment: ... or [apple.se].

Comment: Thanks PrR3 and Filburt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man sudo`:

> ```
>  -s, --shell
>              Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password
>              database entry.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is
>              specified, an interactive shell is executed.
> ```

So `-s` keeps your current shell (bash in this case), while omitting it uses the shell of the root user (sh). Myself, I prefer `sudo -Es` to keep both my shell and environment variables.

Comment: Probably this is not an answer to the users question.

Comment: I think it is, what makes you think it's not?

Comment: @PrR3 practically, the only difference is the shell you're getting. Theoretically, `su` part is excessive, as it runs `su` under root privileges.